# How we can noindex,nofollow the category-product-url?

Tags: magento-1.9, category-products, seo, robots.txt

I want to noindex,nofollow only those product urls in which category is coming in url.

For example : I have product abc.html and it is assigned to 2 categories so it can open by three ways.

**1.** category1/abc.html

**2.** category2/abc.html

**3.** abc.html

I want to set noindex,nofollow for only above 1 and 2 point.Means if a product contains with category url.

Answer (score 0):

Just go to the system configuration and change "Include category in product Urls" to "No", also enable the product canonical. This should have the same effect.

If you really want to change the robots, you will have to write a module. Set an observer to `controller_action_layout_generate_blocks_after` and include your logic into the observer function, much like this:

```
    $head = Mage::app()->getLayout()->getBlock('head');
    if ($head && Mage::registry('current_product') && Mage::registry('current_category')) {
        $head->setRobots("NOINDEX,NOFOLLOW");
    }
```

Comment: The above code will do noindex,nofollow to  both urls with category and without category.

Comment: Sorry, was only a fast answer without testing; you should adjust the condition then to check if the URL contains multiple slashes, or the URL-key of a category - depending on your store data.